# retrieving just one value from the DOM with 100 datas listed through JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

> I am trying to get just one ID when I click the Delete button, but I am receiving the whole list of it. Here is how I tried with jQuery. (solutions in both js and jquery is welcome)
>
> the DOM :-

```
<tbody>
  <tr class="tablerow">
    <td class="delete"> </td>
    <td class="id"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

> appending the data to the DOM (100 data is being fetched):-

```
let apiGetter = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
  apiGetter.map((item,index) => {
     del.append('<li> DELETE </li>');
     id.append(`<li> ${item.id}</li>`);
   }
```

> My Solution that is listing all the **ids** that are in the DOM. (i want the id of the button that's clicked on)

```
$('.delete').click(function() {
  let id = $(this).next('.id').text();
    console.log(id); // 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 ... 98 99 100
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this code

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td class="delete" data-id="1">Delete</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td class="delete" data-id="2">Delete</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class="delete" data-id="3">Delete</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).on('click','.delete',function(){
alert($(this).data('id'));
})
```

**CSS**

```
thead {color:green;}
tbody {color:blue;}
tfoot {color:red;}

table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

It very easy and it will work.